# Как в Android Studio генерировать номер сборки для versionName

Tags: android-studio

Может быть есть какой то способ или плагин для генерирования номера сборки? Например versionName приходится ставить руками, но иногда забываешь его поменять и непонятно, какая сборка у тебя, последняя или старая. Проблема на самом деле в том, что с недавнего времени в AS сначала нужно проект собрать, а после инсталлировать, хотя раньше сборка перед инсталляцией выполнялась сама. Отсюда и потребность генерирования версии сборки.

Comment: уточните вопрос, иначе его закроют :)

Comment: Да, маловато информации. Не очень понятно какие у вас условия. Можно, например, просто вместо версии подставить отметку текущего времени. В 99% случаев будет нормально работать. Или в к-л файле писать номер версии и его подставлять на место нужное. Не очень ясно что вам такого сгенерировать нужно, что аж целый плагин нужен.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а каким образом в versionName можно поставить метку времени? И что такое к-л файл? Спасибо.

Comment: Примерно так: `versionName=System.currentTimeMillis()`, `к-л` - `какой-либо`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот как выглядит сборка в разрезе:

```
Major version ⌄       ⌄ Build version
             v1.3.4 (123)
  Minor version ⌃|⌃ Patch version
```

*Основная версия:* должна быть изменена вручную для больших изменений.

*Незначительная версия:* должна быть изменена вручную для чуть менее значительных изменений.

*Патч версия:* увеличивается при запуске Gradle сборки

*Версия сборки:* увеличивает каждую сборку

*Номер версии:* То же, что и версия патча, это для кода версии, который Play Store должен увеличивать для каждой новой загрузки apk.

Вот как можно автоматически генерировать номер сборки:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        def value = 0

        def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
        if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks) {
            value = 1;
        }

        def versionMajor = 1
        def versionMinor = 0
        def versionPatch = versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'].toInteger() + value
        def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
        def versionNumber = versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'].toInteger() + value

        versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = versionPatch.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = versionNumber.toString()

        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        defaultConfig {
            versionCode versionNumber
            versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch} (${versionBuild}) Release"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
        }

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def fileNaming = "apk/RELEASES"
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def outputFile = output.outputFile
                    if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                        output.outputFile = new File(getProject().getRootDir(), "${fileNaming}-${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}-${outputFile.name}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    ...
}
```

[вот](https://medium.com/prathanbomb/tips-auto-increment-versioncode-of-android-using-gradle-dba0425af97c) вопрос по этой тематике откуда и была собрана интересующая вас информация.[Вот](http://devdeeds.com/auto-increment-build-number-using-gradle-in-android/) еще статья с полным туториалом по автоматическому увеличению номера сборки. В итоге вам нужно получить в градл файл и вытащить из него данные по номеру сборки. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21405744/9363441) прямо есть ответ на вопрос по поводу получения данных из файла в градле.

### UPDATE

читал документацию, и попался на глаза способ для установки номера сборки:

```
int MILLIS_IN_MINUTE = 1000 * 60
int minutesSinceEpoch = System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLIS_IN_MINUTE

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        // Making either of these two values dynamic in the defaultConfig will
        // require a full APK build and reinstallation because the AndroidManifest.xml
        // must be updated (which is not supported by Instant Run).
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ...
    }

    // The defaultConfig values above are fixed, so your incremental builds don't
    // need to rebuild the manifest (and therefore the whole APK, slowing build times).
    // But for release builds, it's okay. So the following script iterates through
    // all the known variants, finds those that are "release" build types, and
    // changes those properties to something dynamic.
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = minutesSinceEpoch;
            variant.mergedFlavor.versionName = minutesSinceEpoch + "-" + variant.flavorName;
        }
    }
}
```

тут даже не нужно брать файлик, все уже готово. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#use_static_build_properties) ссылка на документацию с описанным способом.